# Win32 - how to get event when new appointment or meeting is created in Outlook calendar

Tags: winapi, outlook, com, outlook-addin

I am writing a COM based Addin for outlook to get the appointment or meeting list.
I have written a code to get the list of appointments/meetings.
Now I am trying to find out the event when new appointment or meeting is created.
I have tried almost all events of [AppointmentItem Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem), but didn't get the proper event.
Is there any way to programmatically get the event when user create a appointment or meeting in Outlook calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.ItemAdd) event of the `Items` class. This event is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.

Note, there is no event until the item is saved and the `EntryID` property is set.

Comment: Did you try to save the item after creation?

Comment: What code did you use for subscribing to the `ItemAdd` event?

Comment: I am receiving the ItemAdd event now. There was a minor mistake in my code. 
Thanks @ Eugene Astafiev

Comment: Hi @Eugene Astafiev,

can you please tell me how we can register multiple objects for ItemAdd event of the Item class?